# Keeping references to two actors

Tags: scala, actor

I am making a little 2 player game that will work over the network with actors. Each client sends a message to the server to join and I want to keep references to the senders at that point, but when the second player joins it overwrites my reference to the first one:

```
case class JoinMsg

class Server(port: Int) extends Actor {
  var client1: OutputChannel[Any] = null
  var client2: OutputChannel[Any] = null
  def act() {
    alive(port)
    register('Server, self)
    while (true) {
      receive {
        case JoinMsg =>
          if (client1 == null) {
            Console.println("got player 1")
            client1 = sender
            client1 ! new Msg("Waiting for player 2")
          } else if (client2 == null) {
            Console.println("got player 2")
            client2 = sender
            Console.println("blatted client1?: "+(client1 == client2))//true
            client1 ! new Msg("hi")
            client2 ! new Msg("hi")
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What's the right way to go about this? Thx.

Comment: Spawn a new actor to handle the client that just connected (e.g. one actor per client parented by this main actor) ? Akka is meant to efficiently handle a *lot* of actors

Comment: Thanks -- how do I spawn a new actor that will point to the right one? I tried `client1 = actor(sender)` but no messages get through if I do that.

Comment: First you should move to Akka and give up Scala actors because they are deprecated. In Akka, in `JoinMsg` you would do something like `context.actorOf(Props(new ClientHandler(sender))` e.g. you spawn a new `ClientHandler` actor under this context to which you inject the reference of the sender (your new client)

Comment: Thanks but I want to do this without using Akka to keep it as simple as possible. The purpose is a simple demo of remote actors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Akka it would look like this:

```
import akka.actor._

case object JoinMsg
case class Msg(s: String)

class Server extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case JoinMsg =>
      println("got player 1")
      sender ! Msg("Waiting for player 2")
      context.become(waitingForPlayer2(sender))
  }

  def waitingForPlayer2(client1: ActorRef): Actor.Receive = {
    case JoinMsg =>
      println("got player 2")
      sender ! Msg("hi")
      client1 ! Msg("hi")
      context.become(ready(client1, sender))
  }

  def ready(client1: ActorRef, client2: ActorRef): Actor.Receive = {
    case m: Msg if sender == client1 => client2 ! m
    case m: Msg if sender == client2 => client1 ! m
  }
}

object Demo extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem("Game")
  val server = system.actorOf(Props[Server], "server")

  system.actorOf(Props(new Actor {
    server ! JoinMsg
    def receive = {
      case Msg(s) => println(s)
    }
  }))

  system.actorOf(Props(new Actor {
    server ! JoinMsg
    def receive = {
      case Msg(s) => println(s)
    }
  }))
}
```

Exact same actor code can be used with remote actors. You only need a few lines of configuration and the lookup of the server from the clients is performed with `actorFor`. Read about [Akka remote actors](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.2/scala/remoting.html).

Comment: Thanks, most helpful. I was hoping for something as clear and low on config as Erlang but it doesn't appear to be possible.