# Akka BindException when trying to connect to remote actor: Address already in use

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I am experimenting with Akka remote actors, trying to establish a simple 2 player game over the network. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15534924/589352) to an earlier question gave me a really good starting point but now I'm having a hard time understanding how to adapt it to my situation. ISTM that the original is connecting twice from the same client (see commented section below). What I want to do is run it twice from separate clients, but when I do I get a BindException, Address already in use. I guess that's because each time I run the code it attempts to start the server? I need a situation where I can start and stop the master actor independently of clients connecting and disconnecting. The (minimal) Akka config and exception are after the code:

```
import akka.actor._
//example from answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527193/keeping-references-to-two-actors
// by Patrick Nordwall
case object JoinMsg
case class Msg(s: String)

class Server extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case JoinMsg =>
      println("got player 1")
      sender ! Msg("Waiting for player 2")
      context.become(waitingForPlayer2(sender))
  }

  def waitingForPlayer2(client1: ActorRef): Actor.Receive = {
    case JoinMsg =>
      println("got player 2")
      sender ! Msg("hi")
      client1 ! Msg("hi")
      context.become(ready(client1, sender))
  }

  def ready(client1: ActorRef, client2: ActorRef): Actor.Receive = {
    case m: Msg if sender == client1 => client2 ! m
    case m: Msg if sender == client2 => client1 ! m
  }
}

/* I want to run this once for each "player" */
object Demo extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem("Game")
  val server = system.actorOf(Props[Server], "server")

  system.actorOf(Props(new Actor {
    server ! JoinMsg
    def receive = {
      case Msg(s) => println(s)
    }
  }))

  /* Rather than connecting twice from the same node, I want to run this
     program twice from different nodes 
    system.actorOf(Props(new Actor {
    server ! JoinMsg
    def receive = {
      case Msg(s) => println(s)
    }
  }))*/
}
```

Config:

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
    transport = "akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteTransport"
    netty {
      hostname = "localhost"
      port = 9000
    }
 }
}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at akkademo.main(akkademo.scala)
Caused by: org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:298)
    at akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteServer.start(Server.scala:54)
    at akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteTransport.start(NettyRemoteSupport.scala:90)
    at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.init(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:94)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start(ActorSystem.scala:588)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.start(ActorSystem.scala:595)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:111)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:93)
    at akkademo$.<init>(akkademo.scala:4)
    at akkademo$.<clinit>(akkademo.scala)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

TIA.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When running several instances on same machine you need to configure different ports for them.
In this example it is only the server that needs a know port (9000).
For the clients you can use 0 for a random available port.

Define another configuration file for the clients. `client.conf`:

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
    transport = "akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteTransport"
    netty {
      hostname = "localhost"
      port = 0
    }
 }
}
```

Start the `ActorSystem` in the clients with this configuration:

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
val system = ActorSystem("Game", ConfigFactory.load("client"))
```

In the clients you will lookup the server with:

```
val server = system.actorFor("akka://Game@localhost:9000/user/server")
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick. The declaration of `system` gives me an error though: required type com.typesafe.config.Config. I am using Akka 2.0.5 and scala 2.9.

Comment: Great, that is working for me now :-) If anyone is trying to do the same thing, I copied from https://github.com/akka/akka/tree/v2.0.5/akka-samples/akka-sample-remote to get the server bootable and working.

Comment: it seems that nowadays the port needs to be set via `akka.remote.netty.tcp.port` and not `akka.remote.netty.port`.

Answer (score 4):

You either need to specify the port for client configuration separately or change the port of the server side configuration from 2552 to something else. 2552 is the default port for akka actor systems , when you create an actor system on the client side for lookup(on the same machine) , it also tries to bind to port 2552 if it is not explicitly specified and thus you get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Another easier way could be someone closing all the terminal windows and opening new ones. Was facing the same issue even after stopping all the nodes, but would run in the same terminal instead of opening new ones